# How to remove white border from imageView while using Display Metrics?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-screen-support

I am trying to remove white edges from my Image which has round corners. The image is applied to a "pop up window" using Display Metrics. Pop up window works and it displays the image, however the corners have white borders due to rounded corners of the image.

Here is the code which displays the pop-up window

```
public class Pop extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.popup);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.heightPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*0.7), (int)(height*0.7))
    ;
}
```

}

Here is the XML code which attaches the image to this window

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pop"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/pop_up"
    android:scaleType="fitXY">

</ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried the following to remove the white corners from my PNG which has round corners(one at a time):

Java Class:

```
ImageView ws = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pop);
ws.getBackground().setAlpha(0);
```

XML:

```
android:cropToPadding="false"
android:background="@null"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:alpha="0.0"
```

I tried all these different attributes one at a time, nothing worked. What I am doing wrong? Thank you in advance for the help everyone :D!

Comment: Try adding attribute `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to your `RelativeLayout`

Comment: Did you try `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` in `ImageView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up figuring out how to fix the issue. Here's what I did. In the style XML file, I created a custom theme for the pop up window which and I added the

```
<item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
```

to they style, instead of adding it to the imageView which contains the actual image. The pop up window now has no white borders.

```
<style name="AppTheme.Custom">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Then in the manifest, reference the theme as so:

```
<activity
        android:name=".Pop"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Custom"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
    </activity>
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Add attribute `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to your `RelativeLayout` to make it `transparent`.

**2.** Add attribute `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to `ImageView` to adjust its `bounds` to preserve the aspect ratio of its `drawable`.

**Try this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pop"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/pop_up"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" >

    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help... :D

Comment: If my answer helps to solve your problem then please mark this as right answer.